# VBScript copy files to multiple computers

Tags: batch-file, vbscript

I have two scripts in vbs and bat to change wallpaper on computers. It looks like this:

VBS:

```
Set oShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell") 
sWallPaper = "\\server\Shares\folder1\folder2\test\wallpapertest.png"
oShell.RegWrite "HKCU\Control Panel\Desktop\Wallpaper", sWallPaper
oShell.Run "%windir%\System32\RUNDLL32.EXE user32.dll,UpdatePerUserSystemParameters", 1, True
```

BAT:

```
@echo off
C:\programdata\microsoft\windows\start menu\programs\startup\wallpaper.vbs /TIMER:00 /SILENT /NOLICPROMPT
```

I copy files manually to: C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup on all machines.

It works fine, but now I want to copy it automaticlly to more machines using their hostname. What I need to do? I don't know where i should start. I think I need second VBS script. Does anyone have a script to copy the files on multiple computers?

Comment: In a domain environment you can set the wallpaper via a GPO for any user.

Comment: Couldn't you just say something like `pushd \\hostname\c$\ copy files popd` ?

Comment: alex-k yes, but I can't use GPO in this case.

@geisterfurz007 yes, something like this, but i need vbscript

Comment: I've done this type of thing before, but GPO is definitely the best approach.

Answer (score 0):

If you have admin rights, you can access the administrative shares on a host. Admin shares can be accessed like **\\hostname\c$\ThefolderwhereyouwantoCopy\filename.txt** (C$ denotes your drive)

Simply use a FSO copy command to copy the files...

```
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
strHostPath = "\\HostName\C$\TargetFolder"
objFSO.CopyFile (CopyFromPath ,strHostPath,true) 'true overwrite existing files
```

In the otherhand, if you dont have admin rights you can use powershell to copy files from an UNC path

```
Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock ([scriptblock]::Create("Copy-Item -Path `"\\UNC\path\File.png`" -Destination `"C:\targetfolder\File.png`"")) -ComputerName hostnameYouwanttoRunOn
```

Note: for the above to run you need to have WINRM enabled on both machines. Here is a [link](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/555966) if you want to enable it.